# jEdit in hard word-wrap mode: insert comment character automatically?

Tags: jedit

Probably quite a niche question, but I believe in the power of a big community: Is it possible to set up jEdit in way, that it automatically inserts a comment character (`//`, `#`, ... depending on the edit mode) at the beginning of a new line, if the line before the wrap was a comment?

Sample:

```
# This is a comment spanning multiple lines. If I continue to type here, it
# wraps around automatically, but I have to manually add a `#` to each line.
```

If I continue to type after the `.` the third line should start with the `#` automatically. I searched in the plugin repository but could not find anything related.

Background: jEdit has the concepct of [soft and hard wrap](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/word-wrap.html). While soft wrap only breaks lines visually at a character limit, it does not insert line breaks in the file. Hard wrap on the other hand inserts `\n` into the file at the desired character count.

Comment: Fun fact: The MATLAB editor *does* have this feature for its `%` comments!

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want: I use the macros Enter_with_Prefix.bsh to automatically insert the prefix (e.g., #, //) at the beginning of the new line.

Description copied from Enter_with_Prefix.bsh:

- Enter_with_Prefix.bsh - a Beanshell macro for jEdit
- that starts a new line continuing any recognized
- sequence that started the previous.  For example,
- if the previous line beings with "1." the next will
- be prefixed with "2.".  It supports alpha lists (a., b., etc...),
- bullet lists (+, =, *, etc..), comments, Javadocs,
- Java import statements, e-mail replies (>, |, :),
- and is easy to extend with new sequence types.  Suggested
- shortcut for this macro is S+ENTER (SHIFT+ENTER).